# Jquery form validation/Asp MVC Model Binding - Having period in Name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp mvc model binding to bind a model that has objects in it. So

```
class SuperModel{
public ObjectA{get;set;}
}
```

Then in my view I am using @Html.TextBoxFor(model >= SuperModel.ObjectA.SomeProperty).

My issue is that I am using JQuery form validation, and as you know, TextBoxFor will auto generate a name of ObjectA.SomeProperty, which is what needs to happen so model binding works, but in my jquery validation code, I have:

```
  form.validate({               
            rules: {                   
                ObjectA.FName: {//INVALID BECAUSE OF PERIOD OBVIOUSLLY
                    minlength: 5,
                    required: true
                },
```

So I need Jquery validation to work on a html field that has a name that has a period in it. How would I go about doing this? Or is there a better way. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you put quotes around the input names in the rule definitions?

```
form.validate({               
         rules: {                   
             'ObjectA.FName': {//added quotes
                 minlength: 5,
                 required: true
             },
```

May need to escape the '.' in the input name =>  'ObjectA\.FName': {...}

NB: I would put this as a comment, but I don't have the rep yet for comments.

Comment: Try adding two backslashes; 'ObjectA\\.FName'  I just read that the first \ is interpreted by JavaScript, the second is interpreted by jQuery.

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason, even though I ALWAYS hit ctrl+R to clear the cache, the changes weren't clearing for whatever reason. This happens more often than I'd like. 'ObjectA.FName' worked fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries; I was going to comment "are you sure the cache cleared?" I've had fun with that myself a few times today. ;-) Cheers!

Comment: @JohnEdwards Quick follow-up, the reason that 'ObjectA.FName' works is you likely have a version of Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation which handles escaping the '.'

Answer (score 1):

emgee's solution worked well for me after a day of solving this. I'm using mvc4/razor and distributed jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonnelBio.Firstname, new {  @class = "classname" })
```

jquery code:

```
           form1.validate({ 
            rules: {
                'PersonnelBio.Firstname': {
                    minlength: 2,
                    required: true
                },...
```